# SSRS : How to call API from shared xml datasource with parameters in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that uses both a shared SQL DataSource and an XML DataSource. I've tested the shared SQL DataSource connection and it works. The XML DataSource is calling an API with the parameters that I send to the report.

The URL is constructed like this **Parameters!API_Url.Value & "u_ID=" & Parameters!u_ID.Value & "&sourceType="
& Parameters!sourceType.Value & "&clientID=" & Parameters!clientID.Value & "&applicationID=" & Parameters!applicationID.Value**

I have added a dataset with this shared XML data source but when I open the report the error showed.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cFV4.png)

How can I solve this?

I want to use the shared XML data source in the dataset.